# Dashed unordered list in CKEDITOR

Tags: javascript, html, css, ckeditor

I'm trying find a way to implement dashed list ("–") in CKEDITOR.
Standart html only allows to use squares and circles.

Is there a way to be able to use dashed style for unordered list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not worried about supporting IE7 and older, you can use the :before pseudo selector to replicate bullet behaviour.

CSS:

```
ul.dashed li {
    list-style: none;
}

ul.dashed li:before {
    content: "- ";
}​
```

HTML

```
<ul class="dashed">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```